# How to scroll up in angular 2?

Tags: angular, scroll

I have a blog component with a scroll but when I close it and reopen it the scroll is where it was before, I need it to be shown again from above, how can I do it? I am using angular 12

Comment: Maybe try `window.scrollTo(0,0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that but it killed everything up there except the component I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
document.getElementById('container-3').scrollTop = 0;
```

Add `container-3` in your layout. or you can write in an angular way.

```js
@ViewChild('container') private container: ElementRef;
this.container.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
```